# added .00 at end of value while typing

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">

<script>

$( 'input' ).on( 'input', function() {
  var val = $( this ).val(),
      arr = val.split( '.' );

  if ( arr.length > 1 )
    $( this ).val( arr[ 0 ] + val.substr( val.length - 1 ) + '.00' )
  else
    $( this ).val( val + '.00' )
} ).on( 'keypress', function( e ) {
  return e.charCode == 46 || ( e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57 )
} ) </script>
```

i just try this i can't delete or backspace values. when i do. its had 0 on every time

Answer (score 1):

check `arr[1]` to know if user pressed backspace.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">

<script>
    $('input').on('input', function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val(),
            arr = val.split('.');

        if (arr.length > 1)
            if (arr[1].length !== 1) $(this).val(arr[0] + val.substr(val.length - 1) + '.00');
            else $(this).val(arr[0].substring(0, arr[0].length - 1) + '.00');
        else
            $(this).val(val + '.00')
    })
</script>
```